# android MapView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

I want to have `MapView` inside my `Fragment`

This is my `FragmentLayout` xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#17df0d"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp" >

</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="a.b.c.d"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your_api_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="a.b.c.d.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="a.b.c.d.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

and my Fragment class

```
public class ReportFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener {
    MapView mapView = null; //eventually it is being read from view and assigned
```

when I launch the app, I do not see any map view in my Fragment

Comment: Where is your `MapView` in your Layout?

Comment: you did see it because you didn't added `mapview` anywhere.

Comment: I think you are using `GoogleMap v2` so better to use `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapView`.

Comment: can I use Fragment inside Fragment ? @X'Factor

Comment: @user3833308 Ok. See my answer and implement your MapView.

Comment: @user3833308 You can extends it with `MapFragment`.

Comment: @user3833308 Refer this link http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/52c5d573da0a160bd378852b/com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment?tag=dragonfly

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From [Josh Holtz's example on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551):

You should add `MapView` in your `Layout` like

```
 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

and implement your `Fragment` like

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {

MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)          {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
  }

}
```

Comment: I have some Memory leaks using MapView, any experiences like that?

Comment: Yes, I have it too. did you find any solution?

Comment: Same here, but no solution

Comment: memory leaks here as well, any suggestions?

Comment: Used `MapFragment` instead of `MapView`

Comment: Try to call  mapView.onDestroy() from onDestroyView

Answer (score 22):

Adding to M D's answer:

From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView):

> A GoogleMap must be acquired using getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback). The MapView automatically initializes the maps system and the view.

According to this, the more correct way to initialize `GoogleMap` is using `getMapAsync`.

Note that your class has to implement `OnMapReadyCallback`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_page, container, false);

    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this); //this is important

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(/*some location*/));
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(/*some location*/, 10));
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In case somebody is looking for a Kotlin version of MapView Fragment ;)

```
class MapViewKotlinFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private var mMap: MapView? = null

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    mMap?.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)

    mMap = view?.findViewById(R.id.mapViewPlaces) as MapView
    mMap?.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mMap?.getMapAsync(this)

    return view
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mMap?.onResume()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mMap?.onPause()
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    mMap?.onStart()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    mMap?.onStop()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mMap?.onDestroy()
}

override fun onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory()
    mMap?.onLowMemory()
}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(0.0, 0.0)).title("Marker"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, except that I had to declare `mMap` as `MapView?` not `GoogleMap?`

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but might help someone who is looking to implement maps inside the fragment. Below is the detailed example using kotlin:

First, add the permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Then under the application tag add meta-data in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
       android:value="@string/map_api_key"/>

<uses-library
           android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
           android:required="false" />
```

*To get api link visit: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

Implement play services in build.gradle file:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1"
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.3.0'
```

Add pulgin: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Add maps fragment inside your fragment.xml file:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In your fragment.kt file, implement OnMapReadyCallback. Initialize the google map using getMapAsync(). Below code will let you integrate the google map and point it to your current location.

```
package "Your_Package_Name"

import android.Manifest
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG

import android.content.DialogInterface

import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import android.util.Log

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast

import com.example.utilitybox.R
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient

import com.google.android.gms.maps.*
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceRequest
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient


class FragmentHome : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private var v:View?=null
    private var locationPermissionGranted = false
    private var googleMap: GoogleMap?=null
    
    private  var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient?=null
    private val defaultLocation = LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085)
    private var cameraPosition: CameraPosition? = null
    private  var placesClient: PlacesClient?=null

 
    private var lastKnownLocation: Location? = null
    private var likelyPlaceNames: Array<String?> = arrayOfNulls(0)
    private var likelyPlaceAddresses: Array<String?> = arrayOfNulls(0)
    private var likelyPlaceAttributions: Array<List<*>?> = arrayOfNulls(0)
    private var likelyPlaceLatLngs: Array<LatLng?> = arrayOfNulls(0)


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            lastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION)
            cameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION)
        }

       v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_home, container, false)

        if(getString(R.string.map_api_key).isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Add your own API key in MapWithMarker/app/secure.properties as MAPS_API_KEY=YOUR_API_KEY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as? SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)

        getLocationPermission()

        return v
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        googleMap?.let { map ->
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION, map.cameraPosition)
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, lastKnownLocation)
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.option_get_place) {
            showCurrentPlace()
        }
        return true
    }
    
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap

        this.googleMap?.setInfoWindowAdapter(object : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
            
            override fun getInfoWindow(arg0: Marker): View? {
                return null
            }

            override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View {
                
                val infoWindow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents,
                    v?.findViewById(R.id.map), false)
                val title = infoWindow.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)
                title.text = marker.title
                val snippet = infoWindow.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.snippet)
                snippet.text = marker.snippet
                return infoWindow
            }
        })
        
        getLocationPermission()
    
            updateLocationUI()

          
            getDeviceLocation()

         
        }

  
    private fun getLocationPermission() {
     
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationPermissionGranted = true
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        }
    }
   
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                            permissions: Array<String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        locationPermissionGranted = false
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION -> {

              
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    locationPermissionGranted = true
                }
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI()
    }

    private fun showCurrentPlace() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            return
        }
        if (locationPermissionGranted) {
            
            val placeFields = listOf(Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG)

           
            val request = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeFields)

            
            val placeResult = placesClient?.findCurrentPlace(request)
            placeResult?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful && task.result != null) {
                    val likelyPlaces = task.result

                   
                    val count = if (likelyPlaces != null && likelyPlaces.placeLikelihoods.size < M_MAX_ENTRIES) {
                        likelyPlaces.placeLikelihoods.size
                    } else {
                        M_MAX_ENTRIES
                    }
                    var i = 0
                    likelyPlaceNames = arrayOfNulls(count)
                    likelyPlaceAddresses = arrayOfNulls(count)
                    likelyPlaceAttributions = arrayOfNulls<List<*>?>(count)
                    likelyPlaceLatLngs = arrayOfNulls(count)
                    for (placeLikelihood in likelyPlaces?.placeLikelihoods ?: emptyList()) {
                       
                        likelyPlaceNames[i] = placeLikelihood.place.name
                        likelyPlaceAddresses[i] = placeLikelihood.place.address
                        likelyPlaceAttributions[i] = placeLikelihood.place.attributions
                        likelyPlaceLatLngs[i] = placeLikelihood.place.latLng
                        i++
                        if (i > count - 1) {
                            break
                        }
                    }

                 
                    openPlacesDialog()
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.exception)
                }
            }
        } else {
            
            Log.i(TAG, "The user did not grant location permission.")

          
            googleMap?.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                .title(getString(R.string.default_info_title))
                .position(defaultLocation)
                .snippet(getString(R.string.default_info_snippet)))

           
            getLocationPermission()
        }
    }
   
    private fun updateLocationUI() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            return
        }
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                googleMap?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                googleMap?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
            } else {
                googleMap?.isMyLocationEnabled = false
                googleMap?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
                lastKnownLocation = null
                getLocationPermission()
            }
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.message, e)
        }
    }
   
    private fun getDeviceLocation() {
     
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                val locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient?.lastLocation
                if (locationResult != null) {
                    locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this.requireActivity()) { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                            lastKnownLocation = task.result
                            if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                                googleMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                    LatLng(lastKnownLocation!!.latitude,
                                        lastKnownLocation!!.longitude), DEFAULT_ZOOM.toFloat()))
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.")
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.exception)
                            googleMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newLatLngZoom(defaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM.toFloat()))
                            googleMap?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.message, e)
        }
    }
   
    private fun openPlacesDialog() {
       
        val listener = DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which -> 
            val markerLatLng = likelyPlaceLatLngs[which]
            var markerSnippet = likelyPlaceAddresses[which]
            if (likelyPlaceAttributions[which] != null) {
                markerSnippet = """
                    $markerSnippet
                    ${likelyPlaceAttributions[which]}
                    """.trimIndent()
            }

            
            googleMap?.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                .title(likelyPlaceNames[which])
                .position(markerLatLng!!)
                .snippet(markerSnippet))

          
            googleMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(markerLatLng,
                DEFAULT_ZOOM.toFloat()))
        }

       
        AlertDialog.Builder(this.requireContext())
            .setTitle(R.string.pick_place)
            .setItems(likelyPlaceNames, listener)
            .show()
    }
    

    companion object {

        private const val DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15
        private const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1

       
        private const val KEY_CAMERA_POSITION = "camera_position"
        private const val KEY_LOCATION = "location"
       
       
        private const val M_MAX_ENTRIES = 5
    }
}
```

Once done add custom_info_contents.xml file in layout folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layoutDirection="locale"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snippet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ff7f7f7f" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Add below code in strings.xml file:

```
<string name="map_api_key">YOUR_API_KEY</string>

    <!--Map strings-->
    <string name="title_activity_maps">Current Place Details</string>
    <string name="default_info_title">Default Location</string>
    <string name="default_info_snippet">No places found, because location permission is disabled.</string>
    <string name="option_get_place">Get place</string>
    <string name="pick_place">Choose a place</string>
```

In menu folder create current_place_menu.xml file and add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
     Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at
          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/option_get_place"
            android:title="@string/option_get_place"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

### Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Makes sure you are overriding or calling OnDestroy**View** as well as OnDestroy. Something like ...

```
    public override void OnDestroy()
    {            
        base.OnDestroy();
        MapView.OnDestroy();
        OnDestroyView();            
    }

    public override void OnDestroyView()
    {            
        base.OnDestroyView();
        mapReadyCallbackList.Clear();            
}
```